# nodejs v8.11.2 .foreach not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I'm trying to add a nodejs app we have on dev to production server. I'm getting this error when I run the script.

```
TypeError: team.player.forEach is not a function
```

I know team.player is legit. I console log it and it shows this.

```
player: 
{ name: 'TEAM',
     shortname: 'TEAM',
     checkname: 'TEAM',
     uni: 'TM',
     class: 'FR',
     gp: '1',
     code: '198',
     rush: { att: '0', yds: '465', gain: '465', loss: '0', td: '0', long: '0' },
     pass: 
      { comp: '0',
        att: '0',
        int: '0',
        yds: '40',
        td: '0',
        long: '0',
        sacks: '0',
        sackyds: '0' },
     fumbles: { no: '3', lost: '1' } }
```

The only thing I can figure out is that on the dev server we use v8.9.4 and this version on production we use 8.11.2 though I don't think that should matter in this instance and haven't heard of anyone else having this issue.

Comment: `player` is not an array. There is no `.forEach` on objects.

Comment: Agree with @Derek朕會功夫. What are you trying to do by doing this `team.player.forEach`?

Comment: Trying to go through each player and calculate their stats into our record collection. I'm more annoyed it works on my dev server and not here. Which is duplicated except the versions of node.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `player` is an object not an array. If You want to iterate over it, you should use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values), [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), or [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
Object.values(team.player).forEach(value => {

});

Object.keys(team.player).forEach(key => {

});

Object.entries(team.player).forEach(([key, value]) => {

});
```

Or a [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop:

```js
for(let key in team.player) {
  if(!team.player.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
  const value = team.player[key];
}
```