# Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '(options?: SnapshotListenOptions)

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this error. I am using Ionic

Property 'forEach' does not exist on type '(options?: SnapshotListenOptions)

I can't find any problems with it. What does this mean?

```
  snapshot.docChanges.forEach((docChange)=>
    {
        let doc=docChange.doc
        let topicName=doc.id
```

Comment: There is a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52083486/nodejs-v8-11-2-foreach-not-a-function-error

Comment: Please show more surrounding code than what we see now.  How did you get snapshot?  How do we reproduce this?

Comment: @SanSolo Firebase snapshots are not arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

docChanges is a method, not a property. See proper usage [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots).

```
snapshot.docChanges().forEach(...);
```